# Cups: Processing - "Waiting for printer to become available."

Tags: raspbian, cups

I'm using my Raspberry Pi 3 as a print server with CUPS. Everything works fine, my printer prints the job sent by my devices in the same network. Today I tried to print a document, and I see nothing came out, when I look on the CUPS manage printer page, I see my printer has status: Processing - "Waiting for printer to become available." I figured this is maybe a problem with my printer going into sleep mode (I'm using a none-wireless Canon MG2100 series printer). How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I can't ask clarifying questions on your original post, but perhaps some of these ideas will help you to troubleshoot.

Logging into the CUPS administration page on your Raspberry Pi is your first option to begin troubleshooting. While logged into you Pi, go to http://localhost:631 (http://127.0.0.1:631) to log into CUPS. If you are attempting to access your Pi's CUPS admin page from a computer other than your Pi, you will need its IP address and to have configured CUPS to allow login from another machine.

The obvious first question is, "What changed?" Don't rule anything out at this point.

Other questions that may help:

- Can you find your printer (and its IP address) on your home network?
- Is your printer configured to have a static IP address on your home network?
- Did its IP address change because of a router reset?
- Do administrative actions in the CUPS administration help?

  - Does your printer show up if you attempt to find new printers?
- Can you check the CUPS logs?

Other things that you can try:

- Restart CUPS. (may require sudo before the commands)

  - To stop CUPS, enter the following command:
    `/etc/rc.d/init.d/cups stop`
  - To start CUPS, enter the following command:
    `/etc/rc.d/init.d/cups start`

Comment: @johnny-bra did you find a solution?